# Is it possible to have a free web-service that would check a page and email its HTML code to me?

Tags: email, web-services, webserver, html-email

I just asked a question about whether it was possible to write a web-page-checking code and run it from free web server, and one supporter answered and said that [it was possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734817/is-it-possible-to-write-a-webpage-checking-script-and-run-it-from-a-free-server)  and suggested that I used [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) service.

But he also said that there are no files there, so I would have to work with their database.

I wonder, if there is no such feature as creating files on that free web server, then is it possible to run from that free web server a code that would check a web-page every once in a while, record its HTML code, and mail it to my mail box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is totally possible on Google AppEngine.

I am not sure by you mean "no files" on GAE: there is definitely access to files but in "READ ONLY" mode.

What you have to do is fetch the remote WEB page (through urlfetch API) and use the email API to send it.

Comment: I stated a bit loosely when I gave him the answer referred to: He can't write files, so he can't use files to keep track of his data but will need to write it into the database instead. Yes, files that are uploaded with the application can be read as resources and/or served over the Web.

Comment: Hello,jldupont!!!!
"...fetch the remote WEB page (through urlfetch API) and use the email API to send it."
- Are these API's a part of Java or of Python? I don't know which language I should choose for my task (both are present on Google App Engine). I just asked a question about it, so if you have time and desire, you can answer there.

Comment: I find I get to where I need to go faster with Python but of course if you are more comfortable with Java then it's another story.

Comment: I see. Thank you. So, I think I am taking the Python way.