# Is Java or Python better for writing a web-page-source-checking web service on Google App Engines?

Tags: java, python, html, web-services, google-app-engine

I hope you all have a nice day.

I want to write a web service that would check some web page HTML code every 20 minutes and e-mail it to my mail box. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735028/is-it-possible-to-have-a-free-web-service-that-would-check-a-page-and-email-its-h) I was given a suggestion to use [Google App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/) for this task. Having briefly read through that site I learned that two languages could be used there: Java and Python.

Which one do you think would fit best for my task and, therefore, I would have to start learning? (I don't know either language).

Comment: Thanks to everybody who answered here. So, I think Python is the way to go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've tried both languages with GAE and here's my general feeling about the choice of language for it:

- Python is generally simpler. So, if you're using bare GAE API, Python's one is simpler to learn and simpler to write a webapp in it.
- Java is more compatible. Python's API is generally GAE-specific, while Java API resembles some standard Java technologies (servlets, JDO, deployment etc.)

So, Java is a good choice if you either have an experience with web development in Java or if you're going to use third-party libraries extensively. Otherwise, Python is better.

Answer (score 5):

Both the languages and their App Engine implementations are pretty solid and mature.  As a language, Python is faster to learn, but Java comes with richer tools such as Eclipse that may partly compensate.  A lot depends on what other languages you have background in -- for example, coming from C#, Java would be simpler than for somebody coming from, say, C. For such a simple task, the issues of power of the two languages and additional libraries &c doesn't really come into play.

Answer (score 2):

For your particular task, I'd suggest Python, mostly because of the existence of [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/), an excellent HTML parser that handles poorly formed documents.