# What PHP command would peek into a page and record its HTML code (source)?

Tags: php, url, open-source

Would you, please, tell me what command (or a combination of those) in PHP would check a web-page by its URL and possibly download its code (HTML) into a variable?
Well, I was suggested to use Goggle App Engines for this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735028/is-it-possible-to-have-a-free-web-service-that-would-check-a-page-and-email-its-h), but I am also quite q curious about how much of that task can PHP perform.

Comment: Do you need to parse the data?

Comment: NO. I mean, I've already come up with a way of how to parse it in the way I need it. But what I really need is to peek into a web-page and record it, say, every 20 minutes, storing the data (HTML code) in files and possibly mailing them to me . I guess it's about cron jobs and no free PHP-supporting server would allow me to do that, right? Well, if so, than I still have this Google APP Engine opportunity, except I would have to study Python there first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hello
First Visit this webpage [file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).


If you think the above is to complex use a library 
PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser download here [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=218559)


And Finaly here is the code**

```
<?php
include_once 'simple_html_parser.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://www.google.com/');

// Find all images
foreach($html->find('img') as $element)
       echo $element->src . '<br>';

// Find all links
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)
       echo $element->href . '<br>'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$f = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com');
```

http://php.net/file_get_contents

Answer (score 2):

You could use curl.  Here is a [tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/article/1081)